# Json object doubles on each return

Tags: javascript, php, json

Each time data returns from the PHP file, it seems like the json object are doubled is some way!? When I run the script for the first time I get 5 rows which is the same amount of rows in the table. But the second time, I get the result twice! What have I done wrong in my script?

```
function readData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "read.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      input: 1
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

      var html = "";

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + data[i].text + "</td></tr>";
      }

      $(".contentList table").append(html);
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: `.append(html);`  Your appending.. :)

Comment: you should work on code indentation

Comment: @Keith OK I get it, but is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: Just use .html(html);

Comment: Multiple ways of doing this, like some have said just do `.html()`, or you could do `.empty()` then `.append()` etc.  In a nutshell it wasn't your JSON that was the problem, it was just your rendering.  If you wanted to be really clever you could even do partial updates of what has changed.

Comment: @romanreign Thanks! That works better!

Comment: @Keith Thanks for your comment! I use .html() and that works fine. I understand now that it was not a json problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
$(".contentList table").append(html);
```

to

```
$(".contentList table").html(html);
```

`.append()` will just append more results to the end of the content inside the tag, while `.html()` will completely replace the content.

Comment: Thanks! That was better!

Comment: @3D-kreativ You're welcome! Please, don't forget to choose the accepted answer to help future users :)